# How to use model data to draw mappolyline segments

Tags: qt, location, qml

I want to draw mappolylines corresponding to line segments representing the runways of an airport, the coordinates being provided by a model.
Here is the intended result:
[image: runway]
The main provides the data of the airport and the runways (on Chicago there are in fact 18 runways, here only 2 are recorded, to simplify):

```
#include "airportsmodel.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);


    AirportsModel apModel;
    Airport KORD = Airport("KORD","CHICAGO O'HARE INTL",41.97732,-87.90801,680);
    KORD.addRunway(Runway("04L",42,41.98166,-87.91392,656));
    KORD.addRunway(Runway("22R",222,41.99754,-87.89637,648));

    apModel.addAirport(KORD);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral(":/imports"));
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("airportsModel", &apModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    QObject::connect(&engine, SIGNAL(quit()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    QObject *item = engine.rootObjects().first();
    Q_ASSERT(item);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the airport class, which integrates the class runways. The useful coordinates for mappolyline are returned by rwPosition (). NameRunway () and runwayQfu () will be used to identify pairs of coordinates that match to draw a complete runway.

```
#ifndef AIRPORT_H
#define AIRPORT_H

#include <QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QString>


class Runway
{
public:
    Runway(QString name, int qfu, double latitude, double longitude, double elevation)
        : m_name(name), m_qfu(qfu)
    {
        m_position.setLatitude(latitude);
        m_position.setLongitude(longitude);
        m_position.setAltitude(elevation);
    }

    QString nameRunway() const {
        return m_name;
    }

    int runwayQfu() const {
        return m_qfu;
    }
    QGeoCoordinate rwPosition() const{
        return m_position;
    }

private:
    QGeoCoordinate m_position;
    QString m_name;
    int m_qfu;

};


class Airport
{
public:
    Airport(QString code, QString name, double latitude, double longitude, double elevation)
        :m_code(code), m_name(name) {

        m_position.setLatitude(latitude);
        m_position.setLongitude(longitude);
        m_position.setAltitude(elevation);
    }

    QGeoCoordinate apPosition() const{
        return m_position;
    }
    QString oaciCode() const {
        return m_code;
    }
    QString airportName() const {
        return m_name;
    }

    void addRunway(const Runway &runway){
        m_runwayList << runway;
    }
    const QList<Runway> &listRunways() const {
        return m_runwayList;
    }

     private:
        QGeoCoordinate m_position;
        QString m_code;
        QString m_name;
        QList<Runway> m_runwayList;
};

#endif // AIRPORT_H
```

I think the model should return the complete list of airport runways. It is rwRole who takes care of it, within the model.

```
#ifndef AIRPORTSMODEL_H
#define AIRPORTSMODEL_H

#include "airport.h"
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QDebug>

class AirportsModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AirportsModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QAbstractListModel(parent){
    }
    enum AirportsRoles{rwRole = Qt::UserRole + 1};

    void addAirport(const Airport &point){
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        m_apList << point;
        endInsertRows();
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const{
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        return m_apList.count();
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const {

        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_apList.count())
            return QVariant();
        const Airport &point = m_apList[index.row()];
        if (role == rwRole){
            QList<QGeoCoordinate> rwCoord;
            const auto &runwayList = point.listRunways();
            foreach (const Runway &runwayLabeled, runwayList)
            {
                rwCoord << runwayLabeled.rwPosition();
                qDebug() << "runway : " << runwayLabeled.nameRunway()<< " qfu : " << runwayLabeled.runwayQfu() << " coordinate : " << runwayLabeled.rwPosition();
            }
            return QVariant::fromValue(rwCoord);
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[rwRole] = "runways";
        return roles;
    }

private:
    QList<Airport> m_apList;
};


#endif // AIRPORTSMODEL_H
```

My problem is how to exploit the returned list of runways (rwCoord) with the path as presented in this line: path: [runways] from the main.qml here:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtPositioning 5.5
import QtLocation 5.6

Window {
    width: 700
    height: 500
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test MapPolyline for airport")
    id: win

    Map {
        id: mapOfWorld
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        anchors.fill: parent
        zoomLevel: 12
        plugin: Plugin {name: "osm"}
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(41.97732, -87.90801)//KORD
        MapItemView {
            model: airportsModel
            delegate:  Marker{
//                path: [runways]
                path: [
                    {latitude: 41.98166, longitude: -87.91392},
                    {latitude: 41.99754,longitude: -87.89637}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the path works correctly when directly entering the pair of coordinates, but of course, it is not the goal.

The marker. qml is a simple mappolyline, where a function will be added to gather the different pairs of coordinate when more than 2 runways on a single airport.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtLocation 5.6

MapPolyline {

    line.color: "darkBlue"
    line.width: 5
}
```

So, to summarize :
Is the way to return a Qlist of all the runways belonging to an airport is the right (better) way to do, as the class Airport is designed ?
If yes, how can I use this list into the qml part and add the runways to the path in order to draw the representative line segment?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I think the model concept is not quite suitable for this. Model is a part of MVC pattern which would be not applicable here. All you need is just an C++ proxy object, perhaps singleton which returns list of data.

Comment: @folibis If you look closely at what you are trying to do, it is going to have several Airport, and each airport has an associated route, for me its design is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the route to be recognized, you must return a `QVariantList`, not a `QList<QGeoCoordinate>`:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const {

    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_apList.count())
        return QVariant();
    const Airport &point = m_apList[index.row()];
    if (role == rwRole){
        QVariantList rwCoord;
        const auto &runwayList = point.listRunways();
        for(const Runway &runwayLabeled: runwayList)
        {
            rwCoord << QVariant::fromValue(runwayLabeled.rwPosition());
            //qDebug() << "runway : " << runwayLabeled.nameRunway()<< " qfu : " << runwayLabeled.runwayQfu() << " coordinate : " << runwayLabeled.rwPosition();
        }
        return rwCoord; //; QVariant::fromValue(rwCoord);
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

And then pass directly runways without the need of the brackets:

```
delegate:  Marker{
    path: runways
}
```

You can find the complete test code in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48746536)

Comment: eyllanesc you are still of great expertise and immense advice. If my code is consistent - although failing - it's really thanks to you and again, I'm progressing. I add Edit1 to my initial post. @folibis, thanks for your answer.